# Perl - Why does looping over a hash by its keys and then printing each value result in a uninitialized warning?

Tags: perl, hash, foreach

Whenever I loop over a hash by its keys, and then printing each value, I get an "use of of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string..." warning. Even though the hash is clearly initialized up front. The output I want is printed, but I'd still like to know why this results in a warning, especially as accessing a value directly (outside of a loop) works without warnings.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %fruit = ();
%fruit = ('Apple' => 'Green', 'Strawberry' => 'Red', 'Mango' => 'Yellow');

#works
print  "An apple is $fruit{Apple} \n";

#gives warnings
foreach my $key (%fruit)
{
  print "The color of $key is $fruit{$key} \n";
}

#also gives warnings
foreach my $key (%fruit)
{
    my $value = $fruit{$key};
    print "$value \n";
}
```

Consider the above code. I guess perl sees a difference between the first print and the second print. But why? Why is there a difference between retrieving the value of a hash outside of loop and retrieving the value of a has inside of a loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a hash in list context yields both keys and values. Therefore the line `foreach my $key (%fruit)` iterates over key, value, key, value...

What you need is `foreach my $key (keys %fruit)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `keys` inside the `for` loop. e.g. `foreach my $key (keys %fruit)` ...

Answer (score 2):

It should be `foreach my $key ( keys %fruits )`. I think this is what you actually want to do.